# Connecting PHP to MySQL. My computer has 2 MySQL installed.Which one to connect

Tags: php, mysql

I am only a mere beginner.
Sorry I don't know about connecting to mysql.

I have downloaded mysql from its official site and installed before months.
It is now I have started to study PHP and connecting it to mysql.
I am using wampserver 2.5 ( but i don't know anything about the use of it ).

So to my doubt .
How do I connect php to mysql.
As per the w3schools

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

But what is meant by user name ,password and service name.
I runned the code and it displayed 'connected successfully'(I put $password=" "(blank) and $username="root")
But I think the php is connected to some MySQL that is running along with wamp server (installed along while installing wampserver).
But all my tables and data are in the mysql which i installed before months.

> ***How do i connect to this MySQL (installed seperately in 'local disk D')***.
>   Thanks in advance

Comment: Please some one help me . I am in a hurry .

Comment: You need to know the **ip** address and the **port** of your MySQL that you installed 5 months ago. If you don't specify the port, PHP will assume the default port `3306`. You're on your own to figure out on which port the MySQL you want to connect to is listening at. No one can tell you that except yourself. Google on how to find out the listening port of a program under Windows.

Comment: What next to do if IF i find out port. What is the servername . IS it same as port address.

Comment: Then you use this: `new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, 'database_name', 3306);`. The `3306` is the port. Change that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing a Wammp server also installs a mysql server on your computer which in networking is refereed to as name `localhost` or as ipv4 `127.0.0.1` or ipv6 as `::1`. Put these in your browser address bar and it would all be the same.

During installation it also asks for a password, which is probabaly the one you uses cause otherwise it would not say "Connected Successfully".

Answering your question, if you've installed a second database on your "D" drive it also must use another post cause the default mysql port is 3306 and already in use by the Wammp server installation.

The software is smart enough that it is unable to start the server on that port and will likely use another or not run at all.

But the question really is, why do you have two databases installed on your computer? Especially for a development / learning environment it is not needed and you should just use the one installed with wammp.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .It helped me a lot.

Comment: I have installed 2 MySQL for a reason . I installed the first one by my own before 5 months when I started to study MySQL . But recently i started to study PHP . SO I installed wampserver and one more MySQL automatically installed . That is the reason . When i connect to mysql it connects to the mysql installed along with wampserver. So how do i connect to the other one.How to run the service of the other mysql .Will doing so make make PHP to connect to the other MySQL . will the server name be localhost. How can i find its username .I know its password. is there any query to find the username

Comment: Usually the username is root, how to connect to it? since its on your local computer its localhost but due the fact that a mysql server is already running on it the port is different or the server is not running at all. First find out if the service is really running, if so find the port number and connect to it with localhost:### what that port number is? I have no clue, search for it. However.. I dont think Windows is able to install 2 MySQL services.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i never use wampserver. But, i understand your problem is only on 'mysql service'. If you have started the mysql service on diks D, so you only need to turn off mysql service on wampserver.

Comment: Sorry .I didn't understand what you meant by service. I only know how to open MySQL command line client from start.   Will stopping the service from wampserver enable the other MySQL. If not how to I start its service. What might be its server name . is it same as localhost. What could be its user name